# Is there another way to choose the first 3 numbers from this ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

Im trying to return the first 3 numbers from this arrayList but the way it is I've got the whole array.

```
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        list.add(new Integer(i));
    }
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        System.out.println(list.get(i));

    }
    System.out.println(list);
    return list;
```

There I saw some examples using pick() but I don't understand it. Can anyone explain?

Comment: You could use a hash set

Comment: Your code actually *does* print the first three numbers.  You then elect to print out and return the entire list.

Comment: Do you need first 3 **unique** integers or just first 3 integers?

Comment: @FailingCoder, `System.out.println(list)` actually pretty-prints the list using the implementation in `AbstractCollection.toString()`.

Comment: Really? I didn't know about that. I don't think it's the same with the `java.util.ArrayList` though, right?

Comment: `ArrayList` extends that class through `AbstractList`.

Comment: Take a look at my one-line answer, @Maluco.

Answer (score 4):

Use a sub-list, if you want just those first three elements.

```
return list.subList(0, 3);
```

Comment: to return the first 3 should I use: return list.subList(0, 2); ?

Comment: @Maluco, no. The last index is non-inclusive

Answer (score 3):

First, prefer a `List<Integer>` (the interface) to `ArrayList<Integer>` (the concrete type). Second, you can generate the range you want with an `IntStream`. Then shuffle it, and then return just three elements with a `limit(long)` call. Like,

```
List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(0, 10).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
Collections.shuffle(list);
return list.stream().limit(3).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it with `Java 8` would be to stream 3 random numbers from 0 to 10 and collect them as a list, something like:

```
 List<Integer> listOfNumbers = new Random().ints(3, 0, 11).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
 System.out.println(listOfNumbers);
```

**Unique**

```
 //Stream 3 unique numbers from 0 to 10 and collect them as a list
 List<Integer> listOfNumbers = new Random().ints(0, 11).distinct().limit(3).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
 System.out.println(listOfNumbers);
```